# Why is post-command only working with following alert?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an ajax call (post actually) that works fine if followed by alert('hello');
(The sqlite database is updated by ajaxgastverg.php and the closing alert reports its data and success fine).

After removing the alert("Hello") the post works NOT (the ajaxverg.php does not update the sqlite database and the closing alert does not appear with data and success).

How can I make the post work without the alert("Hello")?

Consulting previous reports I tried to remove the alert('Hello") and substituting "return false;" but this did not help.

```
function popupgastverg2()  
{nr=$('#popupgastverg').data('nr');
cat=$('#popupgastverg select').find(":selected").text();
$.post
    ("ajaxgastverg.php"
    ,{catin:cat,nrin:nr}
    ,function(data,status)
        {alert('data='+data+"\nstatus="+status);
        // I tried here return false; but no effect
        }
    );
    // I tried here return false; but no effect
alert("Hello"); // THIS WAS FOR DEBUGGING ONLY
}
```

Comment: Have you checked into the console log to see if there are any reported errors?

Comment: Well is it a successful call? Add an error handler

Answer (score 0):

I found "the solution", but I do not understand it.
I hope other people can  benefit from this although I have no explanation.

Th program was called in

```
<form id='xxx'> ..... more...
<button onclick="popupgastverg2();"> Deel list </button>
....more...
</endform>
```

Once I changed the button to:

```
<button type='button' onclick="popupgastverg2();"> Deel list </button>
```

everything worked.
Surprise, but a pleasant surprise!